# 403 FORBIDDEN code posting to list

Tags: custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api, error

I am trying to post to a list with a custom form. Each time I try to submit my for the console prints out a "403 FORBIDDEN" error.
 I have Site Collection Admin rights for the entire site.
Here is my code:

```
    <body>

<div id="AddListData">
    <div>
        Onboard Date:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="datePicker"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Name:
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="txtTitle" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Position: 
            <br />
        <input type="text" id="position"/>
    </div>
        <br />
    <div>
            <select id="choiceO" >
                <option selected="selected" value="No">No</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divResult"></div>

<script src="https:x/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="x/jqueryUICal.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    bindButtonClick();

});

function bindButtonClick() {
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
        addListItem();
    });
}


function addListItem() {
    var title = $("#txtTitle").val();
    var position= $("#position").val();
    var date = $("#datePicker").val();
    var oCheck = $("#choiceO").val();

    var fullUrl = "site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('FormDemo')/items";

    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FormDemoListItem' },
            'Title': title,
            'Position': position,
            'OnboardDate': date,
            'O': oCheck
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: onQuerySucceeded,
        error: onQueryFailed
    });

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    $("#divResult").html("Item successfully added!");
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert('Error!');
}

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Run this line in console  `$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()`. Check and let me know  if you are getting request digest value or it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It should work. I have modified your code little bit.

I suspect you are not using SharePoint Master Page in your custom form. So  you will not get request digest vakue directly through `$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()` as it is available only in SharePoint Master Pages.

So You will have to get it first by POST call to "_api/contextinfo"

```
$(function () {
    bindButtonClick();
});

function bindButtonClick() {
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function () {
        GetRequestDigestValue().then(GetRequestDigestValueSuccess, GetRequestDigestValueFailed);
    });
}


function GetRequestDigestValue(){
    return $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
            url:"https://mysiteName.sharepoint.com/sites/RohitW/_api/contextinfo",
            headers : {
                'Accept': "application/json;odata=verbose",
                'Content-Type': "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
    });
}

function GetRequestDigestValueSuccess(data){
    formDigestValue = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
    addListItem(formDigestValue);
}

function GetRequestDigestValueFailed(error){
    // Failure Handler code goes here
}

function addListItem(formDigestValue) {

    var title = $("#txtTitle").val();
    var position= $("#position").val();
    var date = $("#datePicker").val();
    var oCheck = $("#choiceO").val();

    var fullUrl = "site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('FormDemo')/items";

    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.FormDemoListItem' },
            'Title': title,
            'Position': position,
            'OnboardDate': date,
            'O': oCheck
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": formDigestValue
        },
        success: onQuerySucceeded,
        error: onQueryFailed
    });

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    $("#divResult").html("Item successfully added!");
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    alert('Error!');
}
```

Comment: I get a "_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl" is not defined console error.

Comment: @Ben Segarra  It was my mistake. It is also available only on SharePoint master pages. You can directly use your site url. I have updated the answer accordingly. Try it out..